# How to run 2 async calls in sequence?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to asyn call two calls in sequence. But I failed.

The log statement "EVERYTHING DONE" is fired right after "START". Async logs latest.
I think i messed up with async and await.

Thanks for your help.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("START");

    (async () => {
        uniqueAuthors = await getHashtag("winter");
        console.log("getHashtag")

        let uniqueAuthors = await getHashTagMeta(uniqueAuthors);
        console.log(getHashTagMeta);
    })();

  console.log("EVERYTHING DONE");

});
```

Comment: Try removing the inner `(async () => {` and convert the callback into an async function? `async function (req, res, next) {`? --- Also `uniqueAuthors` is getting re-defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` functions return promises. To wait until the promise settles, attach a fulfillment handler with `then` and/or a rejection handler with `catch` (and/or a "finally" handler with `finally`).

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("START");

    (async () => {
        uniqueAuthors = await getHashtag("winter");
        console.log("getHashtag")

        let uniqueAuthors = await getHashTagMeta(uniqueAuthors);
        console.log(getHashTagMeta);
    })()
    .then(() => {                        // ***
        // Completed successfully        // ***
    })                                   // ***
    .catch(() => {                       // ***
        // Failed                        // ***
    })                                   // ***
    .finally(() => {                     // ***
        // Either of the above           // ***
    });                                  // ***
});
```

(You can also attach both fulfillment and rejection handlers by passing two functions to `then`.)

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in a good bit of detail in Chapter 8 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*, and I go into `async` functions and `await` in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved if you remove the inner `async` wrapper and put it on the route controller directly. But make sure to wrap everything in a `try / catch` block to handle errors:

```js
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {

  try {

    console.log("START");

    console.log("getHashtag")
    const hashTag = await getHashtag("winter");

    console.log(getHashTagMeta);
    const hashTagMeta = await getHashTagMeta(hashTag );
    
    console.log("EVERYTHING DONE");
    return res.status(200).json(hashTagMeta);

  } catch (ex) {
     
    return res.status(500).end(ex.message);
     
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your solution attempt is a bit harder than it should be; the below is using await/async:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("START");
    let uniqueAuthors = await getHashtag("winter");
    console.log("getHashtag")

    let hashTagMeta = await getHashTagMeta(uniqueAuthors);
    console.log(hashTagMeta);
    console.log("EVERYTHING DONE");
});
```

FYI - this was mentioned in the comment, but I decided to answer it explicitly with a sample

Comment: Use that only if your router framework supports promises, or error handling won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you never wait for the promise returned from your IIFE (function(){...}()).

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    
        console.log("START");
    
        await (async () => {
            uniqueAuthors = await getHashtag("winter");
            console.log("getHashtag")
    
            let uniqueAuthors = await getHashTagMeta(uniqueAuthors);
            console.log(getHashTagMeta);
        })();
    
      console.log("EVERYTHING DONE");
    
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use .reduce func to archive this requirement, here is the link you can refer to [async calls in sequence](https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2019/how-to-run-async-js-in-parallel-or-sequential/)

```
const starterPromise = Promise.resolve(null);
const log            = result => console.log(result);
await asyncThingsToDo.reduce(
    (p, spec) => p.then(() => runTask(spec).then(log)),
    starterPromise
);
```